# Как добавить любое приложение в список "Завершить действие .." из своего приложения?

Tags: android

Как открыть другое приложение с помощью своего? У меня есть кнопка VK и по нажатию я хочу, что бы открывалось обычное диалоговое окно с выбором приложений. Вот я нажимаю на VK и пока у меня такой выбор: Интернет, Google, а нужно, что бы еще было и "Вконтакте". Пользователь должен сам определять с помощью чего он может открыть ссылку.

[image]

пример: допустим, пользователь должен открыть приложение Вконтакте через мой лаунчер. Он нажимает на кнопку VK и открывается по умолчанию диалоговое окно с выбором тех приложений, с помощью которых может перейти Вконтакт. Там обязательно будет: Google, Интернет и он сам должен в список диалогового окна добавить "Вконтакте"

Вот сам код, как открываю приложение

```
case R.id.btnGPlay:
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://vk.com"));
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
```

Comment: попробуй использовать вот эту ссылку(не прям использовать а пройди по ней и прочитай) на сайт андроида из гугла : http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/distribute/tools/promote/linking.html

Answer (score 1):

Видимо нельзя просто так добавить любое приложение в диалог "Завершить действие с помощью .." , так как для этого разработчиком самого этого приложения должно быть указано в манифесте, что данное приложение может использоваться для данной операции. Из своего приложения вы никак не можете повлиять на это обстоятельство в другом приложении.

[Официальный гайд](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/intents/sending.html) по этому вопросу.

Вы можете добавлять собственные пункты [в диалог "Отправить .."](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/sharing/shareaction.html)

Comment: Я, наверное, не так выразился. Другой пример: допустим, пользователь должен открыть приложение Вконтакте через мой лаунчер. Он нажимает на кнопку VK и открывается по умолчанию диалоговое окно с выбором тех приложений, с помощью которых может перейти Вконтакт. Там обязательно будет: Google, Интернет и он сам должен в список диалогового окна добавить "Вконтакте"

Comment: @Эдуард Вам нужно добавить что то в этот список выбора, чем открывать? Переоформите вопрос так, чтобы было понятно, что вы хотите.